# spring config server cannot refresh by webhook

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I use spring cloud bus and rabbitMQ to refresh spring config. When we update the config and push to the github, the webhook cannot refresh, the response message:

> "{"timestamp":"2018-05-14T09:44:48.230+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad
>   Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
>   `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token\n
>   at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 290] (through
>   reference chain:
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap[\"commits\"])","path":"/actuator/bus-refresh"}
>   ";

But when we refresh through postman or Using the command "curl -X POST  http://436d3d0b.ngrok.io/actuator/bus-refresh" ,it can refresh normally.

The application.yml as shown below:

spring:

application:

```
name: config-server
```

cloud:

```
config:
  server:
    git:
      search-paths: config/*
      username:
      password:
      uri: "github url"
  label: master
bus:
  trace:
    enabled: true
```

rabbitmq:

```
host: localhost
port: 5672
username: guest
password: guest
```

management:

endpoints:

```
web:
  exposure:
    include: bus-refresh
```

Github webhook payload url is "http://436d3d0b.ngrok.io/actuator/bus-refresh" and content type is "application/json";